# "it's even been linked to" VS "it's linked to"

Tags: difference, adverbs, passive-voice

Sleeplessness may also cause inflammation, hallucinations, high blood pressure, and *it's even been linked to* diabetes and obesity.

Sleeplessness may also cause inflammation, hallucinations, high blood pressure, and *it's linked to* diabetes and obesity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two extra words in your second example "even been", although you could just use the word "even" by itself.

"Even" is used to show that something is surprising, unusual, unexpected, or extreme.

So, the second example is just a list of problems associated with sleeplessness, but the first example which says "it's *even been* linked to diabetes and obesity" suggests that those last two problems are more surprising or unusual than the rest of the list.